# Visual SLAM for wheeled robot

Tags: slam, wheeled-robot, odometry, visual-odometry

I would appreciate your help for choosing the appropriate real-time SLAM algorithm.

I am interested in having autonomous robot, thus a SLAM component is needed for autonomous navigation.

The platform is Kobuki robot (Turtlebot2 without Kinect) which has wheel odometry.
To get a better localization, I want to use camera (Fisheye) - optionally looking upwards.

There is a lot of algorithms available online, most of them output 6DoF (do I need 6DoF for a wheeled robot? (x,y,theta) is enough, right?). I tried using several algorithms, but still didn't find the optimal one.

I believe that Loop-Closure is needed as well, because the final application would be to have a robot that coverage the area (visit each point once).

ROS is used to implement this robot, with small dev board (Intel Atom x5 processor).

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you instrument the environment with fiducials on the ceiling?

Comment: Thanks for answering. No, I cannot do that. The purpose is to have robot that can navigate in unknown environment .

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by "There is a lot of algorithms available online, most of them output 6DoF" ?
To be more specific what do you mean by 6DoF output

Comment: @vacky That is like (x,y,z, alpha, beta, gamma) unlike (x, y, theta) that OP mentions. 6 DoF planning is generally used for RC planes as far as I know.